# CALayer cornerRadius has no effect on 4" device (simulator)

Tags: objective-c, iphone-5, cornerradius

I work on dynamically, programmatically layout a view for 3.5" devices as well as for 4" devices. 
As such that works fine. 
But I want rounded corners so that my images appear like playing cards. 
And I get rounded corners nicely displayed in 3,5 inch devices on the simulator for simulated iOS 6.1 and 7 alike. 
But when I choose iPhone retina 4 inch on 6.1 or 7, then the UIImage in the UIImageView is fully displayed. 
It works nicely on simulated iPad devices (in iPhone simulation mode - it is an iPhone only app).

As for today, I do not have any 4" device with me to test it. I can test on a device during the upcoming week.

Hiere is the relevant code:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.imageV.image = self.image; // The image property was set by the caller.

    // Layout imageV within self.view with a margin of MARGIN
    self.imageV.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x + MARGIN, self.view.frame.origin.y + MARGIN, self.view.frame.size.width - 2 * MARGIN, self.view.frame.size.height - 2 * MARGIN);

    // set the raidus and the mask to follow the rounded corners.
    self.imageV.layer.cornerRadius = CORNER_RADIUS;
    self.imageV.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
}
```

BTW: CORNER_RADIUS is 18 and MARGIN is 15. Changing these values has no effect on the issue.

UPDATE: Thanks to Matt I figured out that the problem disappears when I create the UIImageView programmatically. That is some really nice workaround plus it points into the right diretion, I guess, but it is not a solution. Any ideas what setting in the storyboard editor might have caused the problem? 
As far as I can see, auto layout is disabled for all view controllers in this storyboard.

[image: 3.5" device]
[image: 4" device]

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code, obviously, so I have to believe that something else is going on here.

Comment: Let me just check a couple of things with you. Where is the image view created? If in the storyboard / nib, does it have auto layout turned on? If so, you've got a problem because you cannot set the frame directly like this.

Comment: Also, where you say `frame` you should be saying `bounds` - the image view's frame is positioned with respect to the _bounds_ of `self.view`, not its frame.

Comment: However, having fixed all of that, I cannot reproduce the problem, so I presume you have other code you are not showing that is messing things up somehow.

Comment: Thanks @matt, the UIImageView is created in a storyboard where autolayout is disabled. You are right about frame and bounds. However, as self.view is located at (0/0) it happens to work. Do you think this is related to the issue with the round corners?

Comment: It is not my project. I am just adding the flexible layout for the different iPhone screen sizes. So you might be right with "there is something else ...". I am happy to share more code and check upon settings in IB/Storyboard but I'd appreciate any advise on what to look at.

Comment: No, I'm sure it is not related. :) There could be a positioning problem with the frame but this would not affect the rounding!

Comment: I notice another difference in your screen shots: on the second one, the top is pushed way down, as if there were a navigation bar that is not shown. This could be a CLUE!

Answer (score 3):

The answer is simple. The code did work. It did add round corners to the UIImageView object and the maskToBounds worked well.

But the actual image displayed is smaller. I used AspectFit as mode to ensure that the actual image is not squeesed but displayed in its original aspect ration. Because of the longer layout of the iPhone5 dimensions the image only filled a part of its owning UIImageView. I changed the background color to gray for the screenshot and now it gets clear.

So the solution will be that I'll have to calculate the proper size of the image view so that it matches exactly the size of the scaled image. Then it should work.

(I'll update this answer when it is done).

[image]

Update: this is what I finally did: I removed the UIImageView from the Storyboard and deal with it programmatically.

Don't get confused by the complexity. I added another view just to throw a shadow, although this is not related to the original question. The shadow I wanted to add anyway. And it turned out that CALayer's shadow and `masksToBounds=YES` don't really agree on. That is why I added a regular UIView which lies in between the card view and the background view.

Finally this is so much of a hassle for displaying a simple rectangle image, that I think, just subclassing UIView and drawing everything with openGL or so directly into the CALayer would be probably much easier. :-)

Anyway, this is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.state = @0;

    // Create an image view to carry the image with round rects
    // and create a regular view to create the shadow.
    // Add the shadow view first so that it appears behind
    // the actual image view.

    // Explanation: We need a separate view for the shadow with the same
    // dimenstions as the imageView. This is because the imageView's image
    // is rectangular and will only be clipped to round rects when the
    // property masksToBounds is set to YES. But this setting will also
    // clip away any shadow that the imageView's layer may have.
    // Therfore we add a separate mainly empty UIView just behind the
    // UIImageview to throw the shadow.


    self.shadowV = [[UIView alloc] init];
    self.imageV = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:self.image];
    [self.view addSubview:self.shadowV];
    [self.shadowV addSubview:self.imageV];

    // set the raidus and the mask to follow the rounded corners.
    [self.imageV.layer setCornerRadius:CORNER_RADIUS];
    [self.imageV.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [self.imageV setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

    // set the shadows properties
    [self.shadowV.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
    [self.shadowV.layer setShadowOpacity:0.4];
    [self.shadowV.layer setShadowRadius:3.0];
    [self.shadowV.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(SHADOW_OFFSET, SHADOW_OFFSET)];
    [self.shadowV.layer setCornerRadius:CORNER_RADIUS];
    [self.shadowV setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];   // The view needs to have some content. Otherwise it is not displayed at all, not even its shadow.

}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // Just to be save
    if (!self.image) {
        return;
    }

    self.imageV.image = self.image; // The image property was set by the caller.

    // Layout imageV within self.view with a margin of MARGIN
    self.imageV.frame = CGRectMake(MARGIN, MARGIN, self.view.bounds.size.width - 2 * MARGIN, self.view.bounds.size.height - 2 * MARGIN);


    // Calculate the size and position of the image and set the image view to
    // the same dimensions
    // This works under the assumption, that the image content mode is aspectFit.
    // Well, as we are doing so much of the layout manually, it would work with a number of content modes. :-)

    float imageWidth, imageHeight;
    float heightWidthRatioImageView     = self.view.frame.size.height / self.view.frame.size.width;
    float heightWidthRatioImage         = self.image.size.height / self.image.size.width;

    if (heightWidthRatioImageView > heightWidthRatioImage) {
        // The ImageView is "higher" than the image itself.
        // --> The image width is set to the imageView width and its height is scaled accordingly.
        imageWidth  = self.imageV.frame.size.width;
        imageHeight = imageWidth * heightWidthRatioImage;
    } else {
        // The ImageView is "wider" than the image itself.
        // --> The image height is set to the imageView height and its width is scaled accordingly.
        imageHeight = self.imageV.frame.size.height;
        imageWidth  = imageHeight / heightWidthRatioImage;
    }

    // Layout imageView and ShadowView accordingly.
    CGRect imageRect =CGRectMake((self.view.bounds.size.width - imageWidth) / 2,
                                 (self.view.bounds.size.height - imageHeight) / 2,
                                 imageWidth, imageHeight);
    [self.shadowV setFrame:imageRect];
    [self.imageV setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, imageWidth, imageHeight)]; // Origin is (0,0) because it overlaps its superview which just throws the shadow.

}
```

And this is how it finally looks like: 
[image][image]

Comment: And in fact if you look at what I kept saying about the layout - why in the second shot is the image so much lower from the top and higher from the bottom - you will see that that difference _was_ a clue along those lines! Well done. - I didn't solve it, though; I thought of advising you to give the image view a background color, or of checking the content mode, but I never said it.

Comment: Again, thanks a lot. You pushed me into the right direction. Just in case that anybody else runs into a similar problem I'll extend my answer with the final code and the screenshots.

Comment: You can even checkmark your own answer in a couple of days, just to show that the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to some issue with code or configuration you have not told us about. Proof: I ran the following and it works fine. Note that I create the image view in code (to avoid the auto layout problem) and fixed your frame/bounds confusion, and that I've skipped your `self.image`, but none of that is really relevant to the issue you are seeing:

```
#define CORNER_RADIUS 18
#define MARGIN 15
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.imageV = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"im"]];
    [self.view addSubview:self.imageV];
    // Layout imageV within self.view with a margin of MARGIN
    self.imageV.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.origin.x + MARGIN, self.view.bounds.origin.y + MARGIN, self.view.bounds.size.width - 2 * MARGIN, self.view.bounds.size.height - 2 * MARGIN);
    // set the raidus and the mask to follow the rounded corners.
    self.imageV.layer.cornerRadius = CORNER_RADIUS;
    self.imageV.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
}
```

It works fine (and you can prove that to yourself). Here is a screen shot of the 4-inch simulator:

[image]

Therefore the problem is outside the code that you quote in your question, and cannot be analyzed without further information.

Comment: In general, always do (when these mystifying issues arise) what I'm doing here: make a tiny project with just the code that seems to be acting odd, and no more. If, as here, it works fine, that _proves_ that the problem is elsewhere. It only takes a moment and is a valuable analytical tool.

Comment: All right, thank you so far. The issue must be somewhere in the storyboard where I do not see it. I've ceated the image view programmatically and now it works. If it was just about getting over it then your hint was helpful. But the project is from a junior/sudent and I'd like to find out what actually caused the problem. But you are pointing in the right direction. Upvote for now, accept will follow unless an answer comes that narrows it further down.

Comment: Are there multiple storyboards?

Comment: There is just one. It is a rather small project. One of the numerous scrum poker "games". Root view is a tab view controller, then one of its navigation controllers comes with a straight collection view in it showing all cards. When a card is selected then a detail view controller comes up shoing this very card. Nothing complicated at all.

Comment: Okay but why does your first screen shot show no room at the top for the nav bar and no room at the bottom for the tab bar, but the second one does? It seems you're reaching those screen shots in two very different ways / contexts. This makes me doubt the validity of the test at your end.

Comment: Hmm... I'll check about the nav-bar. Could be hidden. The two screenshots may come from simulated 3.5" and 4" devices. The 5" devices shows spare space at the top and the buttom of the view. So far that is intended.

Comment: For the test I just changed the iPhone Simulator modus, re-run identical code and made the screenshots.

Comment: Finally I found it. It is rather embarassing. Simple but I just didn't see it. I'll post the answer in a minute.